# Dynamically create a table and then insert the data dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a procedure to create a table dynamically with user inputted no of columns from 1 to n. I have used below script to create the table dynamically -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLES(COLS IN NUMBER)
AS
TABLE_STMT VARCHAR2(100);
TABLE_COLS VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
     TABLE_STMT := 'CREATE TABLE TABLS(COL';
     FOR I IN 1..COLS LOOP
         IF I = COLS THEN
             TABLE_STMT := TABLE_STMT || I || ' VARCHAR2(50)) ';
         ELSE
             TABLE_STMT := TABLE_STMT || I || ' VARCHAR2(50), COL';
         END IF;
     END LOOP;
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE TABLE_STMT;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_STMT);
END;
/
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d980980de332b7b161939d009f9e2ea8)

I have another table as -

```
VAL
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

Whose rows needs to be split among the columns created in above table. If user input 2 columns, then output should be -

```
col1  |  col2
A     |  B
C     |  D
E     |  F
G     |  H
```

If user input 3 columns, the output should be -

```
col1  |  col2  |  col3
A     |  B     |  C
D     |  E     |  F
G     |  H
```

I have successfully created the table but stucked to insert the data in it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dynamic pivot to convert the rows to columns:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_data(
  i_table_name IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
  p_sql CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'INSERT INTO "' || i_table_name || '"
SELECT ' || LISTAGG( '"' || column_name || '"', ',' )
              WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Column_id ) || '
FROM   (
  SELECT val,
         MOD( ROWNUM - 1, ' || COUNT(*) || ' ) + 1 AS col,
         FLOOR( ( ROWNUM - 1 ) / ' || COUNT(*) || ' ) + 1 AS rn
  FROM   data
)
PIVOT ( MAX( val ) FOR col IN ( '
         || LISTAGG( Column_ID || ' AS "' || column_name || '"', ',' )
              WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Column_id )
         || '))'
  INTO   p_sql
  FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE  table_name = i_table_name;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_sql;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_sql );
END;
/
```

then

```sql
DECLARE
  cols INTEGER := 3;
BEGIN
  TABLES( cols );
  insert_data( 'TABLS' );
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TABLS(COL1 VARCHAR2(50), COL2 VARCHAR2(50), COL3 VARCHAR2(50)) 
> INSERT INTO "TABLS"
> SELECT "COL1","COL2","COL3"
> FROM   (
>   SELECT val,
>          MOD( ROWNUM - 1, 3 ) + 1 AS col,
>          FLOOR( ( ROWNUM - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1 AS rn
>   FROM   data
> )
> PIVOT ( MAX( val ) FOR col IN ( 1 AS "COL1",2 AS "COL2",3 AS "COL3"))
> ```

and

```sql
SELECT * FROM tabls;
```

outputs:

> ```
> COL1 | COL2 | COL3
> :--- | :--- | :---
> A    | B    | C   
> D    | E    | F   
> G    | H    | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=60924d1f88d948007f7fe07f83f32eb5)*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like a solution with pivot you can generate code with analytical function lead:

```
with la as (select chr(level+64)c from dual connect by level <= 8)
, pv as (select c
               ,lead(c) over (partition by 1 order by rownum) c2
               ,lead(c,2)over (partition by 1 order by rownum) c3
               , mod(rownum,3)r 
            from la)
select c,c2,c3  from pv 
where r = 1
```